# TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable (Python)

Tags: python

At line 15, getting an error

> TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

```
import csv
from wsgiref import headers

size = []
gender = []
gender_count = []
final_gender_list = {
    'male': 0,
    'female': 0
}
with open('Clothing.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        size.append(line[headers['size']])
        gender.append(line[headers['gender']])
    for index, item in enumerate(size):
        if item == 'S':
            gender_count.append(gender[index])
        final_gender_list['male'] = gender_count.count('Male')
        final_gender_list['female'] = gender_count.count('Female')
    print(final_gender_list)
```

Comment: print the value of line  after for line in csv_reader & I guess it will represent a value & not a list. That's why error popped up.

Answer (score 0):

According [**to the documentation**](http://peak.telecommunity.com/wsgiref_docs/module-wsgiref.headers.html) and the [**actual code**](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/wsgiref/headers.py), `headers` is a module itself, so `headers['size']` makes no sense.